# Is Postfix relayhost used for emails reaching same domain?

Tags: postfix-mta, mail-server

a very beginner question about postfix

I configured successfully as relayhost sendgrid for my mailserver

`relayhost = [smtp.sendgrid.net]:587`
in main.cf and other settings.

Works good, question is:

Is relayhost used only for outgoing emails to other domains, or also emails coming to my own domain

For example if I sent emails from logger@mydomain.com to my own inbox `it@mydomain.com`, I do not want these to use the relay.
Every environment prod stage dev has their logger example stage-logger@mydomain.com sending emails to it@mydomain.com. Such emails I do not want to use sendgrid but work as before

But if I sent email from support@mydomain.com I want these to go through sendgrid relay, so customer receives the email without being blocked by outlook/hotmail and so on.

Currently I am concerned that my logger emails might use the sendgrid email and I will reach the limits.

The logger just send emails for errors and other things happening in application

In my knowledge relay is used for outgoing email, so normally should be fine in my case as incoming email should stay inside mailhost and not forwarded anywhere but I want to be sure 100% as logger sends many emails and can crash the limit easy if using relay